# how i could install firefox in docker without update depency , only fix missing dependecy?

Tags: docker, dependencies

i have a command and coker that install firefox from a deb but when i trying of apt-get -f install  instead of isntall the missing dependency remove firefox install, what i could do

please help me with this how i could solve

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY firefox_66.0.1-1_amd64.deb /
RUN  dpkg -i  ./firefox_66.0.1-1_amd64.deb ; exit 0
RUN   apt-get -y  -f install



USER developer
ENV HOME /home/developer
CMD  firefox
```

i exxpected install full firefox with dependency

when execute the command for fix appear this

```
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 171 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 4152 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing firefox (66.0.1-1) ...
```

Comment: The dockerfile you have, should work correctly with -f; what is the problem exactly?

Comment: i update my question and put the part when docker remove firefox instead of install missing dependency